# List commits BEFORE the given Commit ID

Tags: git, git-log

My repo top-level hierarchy looks like this:

```
/dir1
/dir2
/dir3
```

I am on `HEAD` and `git log --oneline --first-parent -5 -- dir1/` gives something like the following:

```
abcb COMM-25 Fix latest
ba0f COMM-17 Some stuff
cda8 New files
db7c COMM-9 Feature merge
e20a Init smth
```

There's a lot of cool stuff over the web like `git log --oneline --first-parent db7c.. -- dir1/` to get

```
abcb COMM-25 Fix latest
ba0f COMM-17 Some stuff
cda8 New files
```

or even `git log --oneline --first-parent db7c..ba0f -- dir1/` to limit at both ends

```
ba0f COMM-17 Some stuff
cda8 New files
```

But, hell, **I can't find anything that could help to output all commits UP TO specific commit id**.
I need something like `git log --oneline --first-parent ..cda8 -- dir1/` to get

```
cda8 New files
db7c COMM-9 Feature merge
e20a Init smth
<...>
```

having just the `cda8` hash. **The most recent command above is of course a pseudo-code** and doesn't provide any output in real life (unfortunately :) ).

**So, how can I list all the commits in the specific directory and BEFORE the given commit id (inclusive) without changing HEAD?**

I think I can accept modifying the dir1 contents (dir1 ONLY, not touching dir2 and dir3!), however doing `git checkout cda8 dir1/` or `git reset cda8 dir1/` doesn't have any effect on the consequent `git log <...> -- dir1/` output.

Please help, git gurus!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've tried *too* hard here and that's what prevented you from seeing the solution hidden in plain sight.

What you ask for *is* the **standard log behaviour** when given a refspec. It will log *all commit history* that is reachable* from that point :

```
git log --oneline --first-parent cda8 -- dir1/
```

(notice that I've taken your exact last attempt, **omitting the "`..`"**) should output :

```
cda8 New files
db7c COMM-9 Feature merge
e20a Init smth
...
<follows ALL the rest of commits history (but only those which have modified dir1/)>
```

* *"reachable" in git should be understood as "reachable through a recursive exploration of a given commit's parents"*

Comment: If the goal is to list all of the revs before a commit id, then you'd want to use `commit-id^`, so perhaps `ba0f^` in this case. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Totally agreed. I sticked to OP's example to keep a consistant comparison and focus on his *expected output*, but to technically answer his *title* question, you're absolutely right!

Comment: LOL, how could I miss that?! Thanks a lot guys, works like a charm.

Comment: @RAM237 We've all been there!